# NumericTextBox Precision

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I was trying to get the kendoNumericTextBox to display values as the following:

```
10.2
10.25
10.2504
```

I configured the numeric textbox like:

```
$(".percentage-input").kendoNumericTextBox({
         format: "n",
         min: 0,
         max: 100,
         step: 1,
         decimals: 4
      });
```

Hoping that the numeric textbox would display the values as above; however, the entry allows for 4 decimals, but only displays 2 (until focused, then it displays the 4).

Any idea how to configure the base display to show 4?  Do I have to define it as n4, and if so, anyway to only show digits that were populated?

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the "format" option to something that have more decimal places:

```
format: "#.0000",
```

or:

```
format: "#.####",
```